# Issue creating Json in C#

Tags: c#, json, .net

I am having the following issue when trying to create some JSON in C#.

Below is my code for creating the JSON:

```
                JObject data =
                new JObject(
                    new JProperty("channel", "Test"),
                    new JProperty("terminal", "0"),
                    new JProperty("order",
                        new JArray(
                            new JObject(
                                new JProperty("orderId", txtSessionId.Text),
                                new JProperty("description", "test"),
                                new JProperty("currency", "EUR"),
                                new JProperty("totalAmount", txtPayAmount.Text),
                    new JProperty("customer",
                        new JArray(
                            new JObject(
                                new JProperty("name", "Test Name"),
                                new JProperty("phone", "00000000000"),
                                new JProperty("email", "test@test.com"))))))));
```

This produces this JSON which is incorrect:

```
{
  "channel": "Test",
  "terminal": "0",
  "order": [
    {
      "orderId": "30",
      "description": "test",
      "currency": "EUR",
      "totalAmount": "10",
      "customer": [
        {
          "name": "Test Name",
          "phone": "00000000000",
          "email": "test@test.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like it to come out like this:

```
{
   "channel":"Test",
   "terminal":"0",
   "order":[
      {
         "orderId":"30",
         "description":"test",
         "currency":"EUR",
         "totalAmount":"10"
      }
   ],
   "customer":[
      {
         "name":"Test Name",
         "phone":"00000000000",
         "email":"test@test.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great, thank you.

Comment: Add `))),` before your `new JProperty("customer"`?

Comment: Are you missing close parenthesis for the _order_ array? (Just before opening the _customer_ array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing your indentation makes it obvious where you went wrong...

```
JObject data = new JObject(
    new JProperty("channel", "Test"),
    new JProperty("terminal", "0"),
    new JProperty("order",
        new JArray(
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("orderId", txtSessionId.Text),
                new JProperty("description", "test"),
                new JProperty("currency", "EUR"),
                new JProperty("totalAmount", txtPayAmount.Text),

                new JProperty("customer",
                    new JArray(
                        new JObject(
                            new JProperty("name", "Test Name"),
                            new JProperty("phone", "00000000000"),
                            new JProperty("email", "test@test.com")
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

As you can see, the `customer` object is inside the first object in the `order` array. Move some closing parentheses about should resolve it

```
JObject data = new JObject(
    new JProperty("channel", "Test"),
    new JProperty("terminal", "0"),
    new JProperty("order",
        new JArray(
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("orderId", txtSessionId.Text),
                new JProperty("description", "test"),
                new JProperty("currency", "EUR"),
                new JProperty("totalAmount", txtPayAmount.Text),
            )
        )
    ),
    new JProperty("customer",
        new JArray(
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("name", "Test Name"),
                new JProperty("phone", "00000000000"),
                new JProperty("email", "test@test.com")
            )
        )
    )
);
```